# how to pass data to a view without using if statement and foreach in the show file?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

when I watched youtube Laravel From Scratch [Part 6] - Fetching Data With Eloquent , and I saw him pass data to view without using if statement and foreach, I has been tried but not working

```
public function show(todo $todo)
{
 $todo=todo::find($todo);
 return view('demo')->with('todo',$todo);
}
```

my view without if statement and foreach

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    {{$todo->note}}
@endsection
```

my view when using if statement and foreach

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
@if (count($todo) > 0)
    @foreach ($todo as $item)
        {{$item->note}}
    @endforeach
@endif

@endsection
```

and I recievied an error

```
Property [note] does not exist on this collection instance
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emyIlJPxZr4&list=PLillGF-RfqbYhQsN5WMXy6VsDMKGadrJ-&index=6

Comment: can you do `return $todo;` and provide the result?

Comment: btw, he used both if statement and foreach in the middle of the video.

Comment: at 11:51 and 12:01 in video, he didn't used  if statement and foreach, then he refresh page and it still get data

Comment: that's two different pages two blade file, one is index which show all the posts, second is show blade file, which shows single post. so you do not need to foreach and if.

Comment: I tried same code but i don’t same result

Comment: can you update your question? do you want to do the index page or the show page?

Comment: can you do `return $todo;` and provide the result?

Comment: @AndySong yes, i do and Result is json type, but I still can not get data to the show page

Comment: can you show me the result.!

Comment: ```[[{"id":1,"note":"to do one","created_at":"2020-04-12 08:25:00","updated_at":"2020-04-13 07:20:54","description":"description for todo one"}]``` here is result when I  ```return $todo;```

Comment: this is returning a collection. not an object which is strange. see my answer check if it works

Comment: So you're saying you're returning `$todo` on your show function and you're getting a collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the property doesn't exist is because the result is a collection instead of an array (found in the op comments)

So you're trying to get `note` from an collection that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "note":"to do one",
    "created_at":"2020-04-12 08:25:00",
    "updated_at":"2020-04-13 07:20:54",
    "description":"description for todo one"
  }
]
```

When you call `$todo->note` you're searching this line:

```
[
  { # <-- You're searching this line
    "id":1,
    "note":"to do one",
    "created_at":"2020-04-12 08:25:00",
    "updated_at":"2020-04-13 07:20:54",
    "description":"description for todo one"
  }
]
```

So your code is returning a collection instead of an array. An array would look like this:

```
{ # <-- Starts with open curly bracket instead of open square bracket
  "id":1,
  "note":"to do one",
  "created_at":"2020-04-12 08:25:00",
  "updated_at":"2020-04-13 07:20:54",
  "description":"description for todo one"
}
```

You need to figure out why it's sending a collection.

From the look of your code, I find a potential issue with this:

```
public function show(todo $todo) # <- What is 'todo $todo'?
{
 $todo=todo::find($todo);
 return view('demo')->with('todo',$todo);
}
```

What is `todo $todo`, are you calling the show function somewhere? By default Laravel sends that ID via the web route. So try updating it to this:

```
public function show($id) #<-- change this to '$id'
{
 $todo = Todo::find($id); #<-- Change this to '$id'
 return view('demo')->with('todo',$todo);
}
```

Let me know if that resolves it.

**Edit: And you really need to fix your capitalization.**

Comment: @MinhTrung Awesome! That's great to hear. Please mark this as the correct answer to help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$todo=todo::find($todo)->first();
```

Comment: the problem is `show()` function,  I didn't knew another way,  until I tried 

`public function show(todos $todo)
        {
            return view('todolist.show',compact('todo'));
        }` 
and 
`public function show($id)
    {
        $todo=todos::find($id);
        return view('todolist.show',compact('todo'));
    }`